# Evaluating $\int_{\theta}\kappa_{s}\cos(s(\theta-\mu_{s}))\exp\left(\kappa_{q}\cos(\theta-x)\right)\,d\theta $

Tags: integration, expected-value, entropy

I have the following expression I am trying to evaluate
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\kappa_{s}\cos(s(\theta-\mu_{s}))\exp\left(\kappa_{q}\cos(\theta-x)\right)\,d\theta
$$
where $\kappa_s,\,s,\,\mu_{s},\,x$ and $\kappa_{q}$ are all constant in $\theta$, and $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$.  $s$ is an integer.

In the somewhat simpler case of
$$
\int_{\theta}\kappa_{s}\cos(\theta-x)\exp\left(\kappa_{q}\cos(\theta-x)\right)\,d\theta
$$
I can make some progress using Feynman's trick (differentiating under the integral), but when the arguments of the trigonometric functions are different I am completely lost.

This question arises when I want to take expectations of some types of circular distributions (such as a generalised von-Mises) with respect to another circular distribution (in this case a standard von-Mises.  Note that the second integral is, in effect, just calculating the entropy of the vM distribution.

One final thing to note is that I will eventually  be differentiating through the first expression with respect to the parameters $\kappa_s,\,\mu_{s}$ and $\kappa_{q}$, so if there is an approach whereby differentiating first and then integrating is feasible, that would also be great news!

Are there any tricks I can use here to evaluate the first integral?  I'm quite okay if I can't use elementary functions, as long as reasonably good approximations exist for this hypothetical special functions.

Comment: You take definite integral from 0 to $2\pi$ or it is indefinite integral?

Comment: If you take definite integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $s$ is integer, then result can be represented in terms of Bessel funciton $I_s$.

Comment: Definite integral is okay, I'll edit the question now to reflect this

Comment: Is $s$ integer? Why do you need approximation for special function? If it is numerical problem, why not to solve it with numerical methods?

Comment: Yep, I've defined $s$ to be an integer in the question.  It's not just a numerical problem - I would like to be able to prove some theoretical results about these expectations and their role in an optimisation I'm working on.  At worst case, I can evaluate the expression numerically, but if I can express it as some function of modified Bessel functions, for example, I can use existing approximations inside packages like numpy, which would probably be faster and more accurate than something I would code up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}k_s\cos(s(\theta-\mu_s))\exp(k_q\cos(\theta-x))d\theta$$
Using substitution $t=\theta-x$
$$I=\int_{-x}^{2\pi-x}k_s\cos(st+sx-s\mu_s)\exp(k_q\cos t)dt$$
Using periodicity by $t$
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}k_s\cos(st+sx-s\mu_s)\exp(k_q\cos t)dt$$
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}k_s\cos(st)\cos(sx-s\mu_s)\exp(k_q\cos t)dt-\int_{0}^{2\pi}k_s\sin(st)\sin(sx-s\mu_s)\exp(k_q\cos t)dt$$
Using periodicity by $t$
$$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(st)\cos(sx-s\mu_s)\exp(k_q\cos t)dt-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}k_s\sin(st)\sin(sx-s\mu_s)\exp(k_q\cos t)dt$$
Using oddity of function $\sin(st)$
$$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}k_s\cos(st)\cos(sx-s\mu_s)\exp(k_q\cos t)dt$$
Using evenness of function $\cos(st)$
$$I=2 k_s \cos(sx-s\mu_s)\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(st)\exp(k_q\cos t)dt$$
Using formula $I_n(z)=1/\pi \int_0^\pi \exp(z\cos\theta)\cos n\theta\ d\theta$ (equ. 5 from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html)
$$I=2\pi k_s \cos(sx-s\mu_s)I_{s}(k_q)$$